# jQuery animate parameter only works when adding 0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

Following is my code written in swiperight event(what it does is like on swiping right it changes the image in the div)

```
$("#divimglstdetails").animate({ marginRight: 280 },0,100).animate({ marginRight: 0 }, 100);
      });
```

what i would love to know is what does the 0 in `animate({ marginRight: 280 },0,100)` mean..i guess 100 is the duration in ms..here my codes swipe right works well when adding 0 else on swiping right it will flicker and change the image..

Comment: I think 0 is used as the duration and 100 get ignored. You should use callback function of animate because here both animate seems to be played both together. You should provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue. Test by changing the first animate to css() and see if it has same behaviour

Comment: but if i am using 100 at first rather than 0 the image transition happens like flickering...

Comment: Ya because both animations are played in same time. Animate use some delay/timeout which make it work like async, that's why you should use the callback function of first animate

Answer (score 2):

If you want the second animation happening AFTER the first, you need it as a callback function. Also, the first number should be the animation time, and after that you need the easing. E.g.

```
$("#divimglstdetails").animate({marginRight: 280},1000,'swing',function(){
  $(this).animate({marginRight: 0},1000,'swing');
});
```

Comment: using 1000 as delay will show at OP what he couldn't see using 100 in debugging purpose, +1

Comment: Yeh it's always best to slow animation down when it's difficult to see what the process is.